# js:scope of this inside an object on keypress event

Tags: javascript

Here is my JS simple script:

```
var Chat = function() {
    console.log("init");
    this.debug = function (txt) {
        console.log(txt);
    }
    document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').addEventListener("keypress", keyPressedFunction, false);
    this.keyPressedFunction = function(e){
        console.log("keyPressed");
    }   

    this.sendText = function() {
        var texte = document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').value;
        if (texte=="") return;
        document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').value =""
        this.debug("sendTexte:"+texte);     
    }
    this.receiveText = function(username, texte) {      
    }

}
var chat = new Chat();
```

My problem comes from:

```
    document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').addEventListener("keypress", keyPressedFunction, false);
    this.keyPressedFunction = function(e){
```

**Error Uncaught ReferenceError: keyPressedFunction is not defined**

If I use:

```
document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').addEventListener("keydown", this.keyPressedFunction, true);
```

then keyPressedFunction is never called.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghLfhb6z/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the problem, and then move to what's dangerous about your code.

The problem is that when you call `addEventListener`, `this.keyPressedEvent` doesn't yet exist:

```
// this.keyPressedFunction doesn't exist...so you are registering a 'keypress'
// event to undefined.
document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').addEventListener("keypress",
    keyPressedFunction, false);
// now you define this.keyPressedFunction
this.keyPressedFunction = function(e){
    console.log("keyPressed");
}
// so this is where you should be attaching it to the event
```

You may be thinking about JavaScript's hosting mechanism, and thinking "ah, the `this.keyPressedFunction` definition is being hoisted to the top of this function, so it's available for assigment."  But hoisting only applies to variable and function definitions; what you're doing is assigning an anonymous function to a member property, so hoisting does not apply.

Now on to the dangerous:

When you use a method (a function property of an object) for a callback, the meaning of `this` is lost when that callback is invoked.  (I know you aren't currently using `this` in your callback, but you probably will eventually!)  In other words, when a key is pressed, and `keyPressedFunction` is called, the value of `this` won't be what you expect.  The upshot of this is you have to be very careful assigning methods to callbacks or events.  If you want to do it, you'll have to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).  Here's your code re-written in the correct order, and using `bind`:

```
this.keyPressedFunction = function(e){
    console.log("keyPressed");
}
document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').addEventListener("keypress",
    this.keyPressedFunction.bind(this), false);
```

Answer (score 2):

place your function before you use its referenc...then use this.keyPressedFunction...then is 'keypress' a valid native js event ?
http://jsfiddle.net/ghLfhb6z/4/

yes there was the errors I told, in fact most important is to place your event handlers at the end, check the right event, and use this if the function is on this :

```
var Chat = function() {
    console.log("init");
    this.debug = function (txt) {
        console.log(txt);
    }

    this.keyPressedFunction = function(e){
        console.log("keyPressed");
    }   

    this.sendText = function() {
        var texte = document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').value;
        if (texte=="") return;
        document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').value =""
        this.debug("sendTexte:"+texte);     
    }
    this.receiveText = function(username, texte) {      
    }
    // place this at the end
    document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').addEventListener("keydown", this.keyPressedFunction, false);
}
var chat = new Chat();
```

Comment: Your answer is correct (and first) but you really should paste your code in your answer and not just rely on the jsfiddle to keep a copy.

Answer (score 0):

@dmidz has provided a correct answer that will solve your problem, but if your `keyPressedFunction` only needs to be referred to code inside your `Chat()` module, then you don't need to make them properties of `this` (`Chat`):

```
var Chat = function() {
    console.log("init");

    function debug(txt) {
        console.log(txt);
    }

    function keyPressedFunction(e){
        console.log("keyPressed");
    }   

    this.sendText = function() {
        var texte = document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').value;

        if (texte=="") return;

        document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput').value ="";

        debug("sendTexte:"+texte);     
    }

    this.receiveText = function(username, texte) {      
    }

    document.getElementById('shoutBoxInput')
            .addEventListener("keypress", keyPressedFunction, false);
}
```

If you do this, then you don't necessarily have to declare your functions before you use them, but it would be good style to do so nonetheless.